Github always get 404 not found
Github always get 404 not found when someone search my username or use my profile link
all my projects also are not accessable i can view my projects and repositories but no one can see them
i tried to change password but nothing changed

Hello, try checking https://github.com/settings/profile and go to Contributions & activity. Did you perhaps check the "Make profile private and hide activity" option? (disclaimer: I didnt test this)

@artikandri I checked this but it isn't  checked the account is public
